# Having issues with CSS3 background colors

Tags: html, css

Basically there should be a background color for the whole navbar across the screen, but it isn't showing up when I run the code.  I would expect them to format everything inside the navigation div to that color, but it doesn't.  I am fairly new to HTML5 and CSS3, so it could be a stupid mistake, but I have done some research and can't find any answers.

```css
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #1d517e;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003b6e, #1d517e);
}

#navigation ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul.left {
  float: left;
}

#navigation ul.right {
  float: right;
}

#navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 10px 5px 10px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#navigation ul.left li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation ul.right li {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="left">
   <a href="electronics/electronics.html" class="clicker"><li>Electronics</li></a>
   <a href=""><li>Gardening</li></a>
   <a href=""><li>Cooking</li></a>
   <a href=""><li>Art</li></a>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
   <a href="" id="about-us"><li>About Us</li></a>
  </ul>
  </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that on navigation you are overriding your background-color property with the background property.

Comment: In my opinion, floating the parent div is the lazy way of handling this. This may also cause unwanted overlapping of other content.

Comment: Agree with @Matthew , this isn't a good solution, you will end up with more problems doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, since you're floating the `ul`s, you must add `float: left` to their parent, `#navigation` too. Otherwise it will just have zero height and that's why the background isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're floating the `ul` . You will need to clear them.

Try adding this:

```
#navigation:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
}
```

Also, `ul.right` needs to have `li` first and `a` inside `li`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by a background colour, you're meaning the colour defined in the `navigation` div. Your `navigation` div has `height: auto` on it. You're floating the navigation links, but not clearing the floats or floating the parent. Because there is nothing for it to adjust based on, it takes up a height of 0 pixels by default.

Either float the parent:

```
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  float: left; /* or height: 30px; */
  background-color: #1d517e;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003b6e, #1d517e);
}
```

Set a fixed height on the parent:

```
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1d517e;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003b6e, #1d517e);
}
```

Or clear the floats (using `overflow: auto` is preferred):

```
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #1d517e;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003b6e, #1d517e);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Which approach you go with is up to you :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: For OP: Floating the parent may cause unwanted overlapping of other content.

Comment: You should clear the parent, not one of the children.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your background on the `#navigation` div is not showing on the navbar is because both of the children `ul`s are floating. This makes it so that the parent div does not have a height. You can fix this by either adding a height to `#navigation` like so:

```
#navigation {
    height: 29px;
}
```

or you can add a `.clearfix` class to the `#navigation` div with the css below:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

and add the class to your div like so:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="navigation"></div>
```

It is nice to create a `clearfix` class because you will be able to use this in your project everywhere else you have this issue. This will also allow you to get rid of that `clear` div you have at the bottom. If you want to learn more about clearfix here is the article I always refer too, [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). There a lot of articles to read about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `height:auto;` with `height:29px;` for `#navigation`

Answer (score 0):

The `clearer` div should be placed inside the navigation bar just after the floated divs and the `clear:both` css should apply to it, currently it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

hope this helps